# Haskell missing files in base package

Tags: haskell

I have never had this before but today I tried to use ghc and get:

```
could not find module
there are files missing in the base-4.10.0.0 package
```

ghc-pkg check returns:

https://pastebin.com/aCmr9igi

Comment: Please include the exact command you ran, any relevant source files, and the *exact* error you got. It was good to include the output of ghc-pkg check. You can safely ignore the warnings about haddock; I didn't see any other lines when I scrolled through quickly, but could you use grep or similar to verify that all of ghc-pkg check's output is about missing haddocks? Also, site rules say you should include all information relevant to the question here on StackOverflow itself (rather than using pastebins).

Comment: That said, given the current information, I assign high probability to the simplest solution being "reinstall GHC".

Comment: @DanielWagner Tried reinstalling GHC, didn't fix. I get this error for any module used. Sorry for using pastebin, i thought it would be easier for formatting than pasting it all in here because its quite big.

Comment: What system you are using, which ghc version, do you use stack  or cabal?

Comment: Arch Linux - ghc version 8.2.1, dont use stack or cabal.

Comment: Exact same issue here - also on Arch with 8.2.1

Answer (score 14):

I had the exact same issue. Installing `ghc-static` fixed it.

Comment: But 1Gb installed pkg to fix this --'

Comment: @meyer1994 Yeah, Haskell seems to be pretty bad about that. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858585/why-is-ghc-so-large-big

Answer (score 12):

You probably need to tell `ghc` to use shared libraries via the `-dynamic` flag, e.g.

```sh
$ ghc --make -dynamic path/to/file.hs
```

Doing this means you do not need to install the `ghc-static` package.

Comment: @meyer1994 If you're on Arch, you can do `pacman -Ql ghc` and you'll see that all of the compiled files are .dyn_hi as opposed to .hi, which are loaded via -dynamic

Comment: Is there a particular reason for Arch to save them all as .dyn_hi? Why not just save as .hi? I imagine it is memory related(?).

Comment: I'm nit entirely sure, but here's a somewhat related discussion on the topic - https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3409

Answer (score 6):

Try to tell `ghc` to build dynamically linked object files and executables, e.g., by

```
cabal install --dependencies-only --ghc-option=-dynamic
```

Comment: fails, saying `cabal: Invalid package ID: .`

Comment: Well, you need to provde the package id at the end of the command.